# In Mac OSX Yosemite terminal when line goes too long it starts overwriting itself because there is no line feed

Tags: macos, terminal

I put some automatically executable code for terminal (inside .profile, because I am a root user) so the git is nicely colored. Git is indeed nicely colored but now I have the problem of overlapping line when it goes into second row, it just starts overwriting itself. This is the part for PS1 that I put and then it started causing problems:

PS1='[$(tput setaf 7)]\u@[$(tput setaf 2)]\h:[$(tput setaf 4)]\w$(tput setaf 1)]$(parse_git_branch)[$(tput sgr0)] $ '

Does anyone know a good literature for this PS1 - terminal display feature? I am really new to the mac osx's terminal and don't have a clue to what PS1 is (except that it can ruin terminal or make it better if you really know what you're doing)? Thanks guys!

Comment: There's plenty of information on bash if you don't limit yourself to OS X, but also look at information on Linux or other Unixes. Googling "bash ps1" can make you lose many hours of productivity. (You're not working as root though, are you? That would be a serious problem.)

Comment: Thanks molbdnilo. Yes I am working as root. I read on a lot of places I shouldn't be doing that, but it seems like the easieast thing to do, regarding the permissions, ie. I don't need to set everything up, I already have all the permissions. Don't get me wrong, but this root issue is not my problem :) my problem is why do I have scrambled Terminal.... except if it has something to do with it? Which I think it doesn't? Does it? Well, I do plan to switch from using the root, but I will focus on my problem, and not on this root thing, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how the prompt is defined:

```
PS1='[$(tput setaf 7)]\u@[$(tput setaf 2)]\h:[$(tput setaf 4)]\w$(tput setaf 1)]$(parse_git_branch)[$(tput sgr0)] $ '
```

You did not mark off the parts of the prompt which send characters to the terminal (for changing colors) which are *nonprinting*.  Do that with `\[` and `\]` markers, found in the bash manual *[6.9 Controlling the Prompt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)*:

> **`\[`** Begin a sequence of non-printing characters. This could be used to embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt.
>
> **`\]`** End a sequence of non-printing characters.

Here is a prompt which escapes the brackets (and adds one):

```
PS1='\[$(tput setaf 7)\]\u@\[$(tput setaf 2)\]\h:\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\w\[$(tput setaf 1)\]$(parse_git_branch)\[$(tput sgr0)\] $ '
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, that worked! I lost couple of hours to no avail looking for a way to solve this...... I will research more on this so I understand it fully.